# UFW apparently causing SSH to timeout despite specific rule

Tags: ssh, ufw, lan

I'm new to SSH and ufw and would like to understand why one type of rule works between two Linux Mint computers on the same home LAN but another does not seem to work.

I just wanted to allow one computer to SSH into the other. To start with I checked that it does work if both firewalls are disabled and I can also see that SSH is using the default port 22.

Then, using the following example local IP addresses

```
10.0.0.2  primary machine - where I want to be sitting and typing in the eventual SSH session
10.0.0.7  remote machine - the one that I'm logging into remotely
```

**ATTEMPT #1**  I set up this rule on the remote machine and left the firewall on the primary machine disabled:

```
sudo ufw allow from 10.0.0.2 proto tcp to any port 22
```

but without luck (i.e. SSH times out).

**ATTEMPT #2** I then deleted that rule and tried being even more specific - I entered a rule through gufw with "sudo ufw status numbered" showed as

```
     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] 10.0.0.7  22                ALLOW IN    10.0.0.2  22
```

also with no SSH access.

**ATTEMPT #3** Finally I reset it again and instead used

```
sudo ufw allow 22/tcp
```

and this finally allowed SSH access. It also works if I re-enable the primary machine's firewall using the default home setting.

QUESTION 1  So, I get it that the last rule attempt is much less restrictive but I don't see what was wrong with either of the first two attempts.

QUESTION 2  Also, in my travels accross the web I've noticed that attempt 3 is quite commonly advised. In my beginners worldview it seems to me that something that only does exactly what I want and no more should obviously be safer so I don't understand why such a wide open approach is recommended.

Comment: I am so sorry for my confusing answer! Somehow I had thought that you configured the `ufw` rule on the host, not the remote. Guess I need to start drinking again!

Comment: Does `ssh -v 10.0.0.7` give any indication as to why it's timing out?

Comment: Well, its a little surprising. On retesting I was surprised to find that approach 1 works ok, I'm wondering what else had changed in the meantime. On the other hand approach 2 still doesn't work and gives the error "ssh: connect to host 10.0.0.7 port 22: Connection timed out"

Comment: I've had the same issue with Warpinator. It works if I write a pair of rules like "sudo ufw allow 42001/tcp" (and also for 42000)but not if I write something more specific like "sudo ufw allow from 10.0.0.7 port 42001 to 10.0.0.2 port 42001" (obviously as a symmetrical pair with the other machine too and also both using both ports 42000 and 42001)

Comment: Are you seeing any UFW blocking messages in the systemd journal? SSHD? Try starting the sshd daemon manually in debug mode: `sshd -Dd`